# python code for calculating session id randomness

Tags: algorithm, session, random, python-2.7, security

I have a list of 1000 session ids. the session-id lengths are of 32 characters each. What is the most efficient algorithm which I can use to determine the randomness or variation at each character level? I am new to python, can somebody help me develop a python code snippet for the same?
Just for reference, Sequencer tool in Burpsuite gives a randomness graph for each 10 character positions if the token length is 10 characters. (algorithm is unknown to me)

Comment: If you're worried about the effective spreading of the hash function that generates your ids, you could look up the hashing algorithm used.  If it is md5 or sha1, you're fine and have nothing to worry about.

Comment: its a legacy app,some custom algorithm has been used(uses time stamp to generate ids). i have seen some anomalies in particular character positions which are not random enough

Comment: "Anomalies in particular character positions" need not equate to a security problem, and I don't think 1000 session IDs are a big enough `n` for that kind of analysis anyway. What should be done is an analysis of the *algorithm* used, not of the *cipher* created. And no, I do not know any such tool (probably for the above reasons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how Burp does it but one way to determine the variation at each character level would be to do character frequency analysis for each position in the session ids.

The premise is that you'd expect that all character are equally likely to appear at a position across all session ids (the distribution of characters is uniform). Let's say you have collected/generated 100 session ids which are numeric (so possible characters at each position would be 0-9) you'd expect that each digit would appear 100/10=10 times at each position.

Now for each position in the sequences build a histogram with how many time a character actually appears at that position across all session ids.

To figure out how likely is your observed character distribution at each position given that you'd expect them to be uniformly distributed you can use a statistical test like the [Chi Squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test).

I've written a simple Python character count tester using the Chi Squared test here: https://github.com/decbis/salr. I'll add more tests in the future.